# Windows proxy settings group policy

Tags: windows-server-2003, proxy, group-policy

I created a GP for internal proxy, it works for all new machine users but old users still find old configuration. How to force the GP refresh overriding current settings at logon?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Policy updates can be forced with the command `gpupdate /force`.

Comment: I know, but i should run that command in each computer... how to force all the domain?

Comment: `gpupdate` can be run on [remote computers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490983.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that the settings are not being reapplied for users who have already received the policy and subsequently changed their settings, have a look at `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Group Policy\Internet Explorer Maintenance policy processing`

Specifically, the `Process even if the Group Policy objects have not changed` setting will reapply the IE policy in case the user has changed it.

Details [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978526)

Comment: I aspect that the user-policy will be reapplied for each logon... am I wrong?

Comment: Not sure about each logon, but certainly each time the policy is reapplied.